# partial font styling in spanlabel

Tags: codenameone

I want a spanlabel show text like

> **`code`name** *one*

and `code` is blue and bold, `name` is red and bold. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't supported by `SpanLabel`. You can either use a BrowserComponent and style the entries or use several different labels in a `FlowLayout` `Container` thus giving each of them the ability to be styled on its own.